# How it is possible to make a vertical space between first paragraph with top of a page?

Tags: spacing

Look at this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \parindent=0pt% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
}

\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose}
\author{Sina Gholizadeh}
\date{Ph.D. Applicant}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle% prints the title block
\section*{}
\section*{}
\paragraph*{}
This is an example.


\end{document}
```

This is a sop sample I found in tex.stackexchange, I want to increase a vertical space between first paragraph and the what are in top of the page? I used

```
\section*{}
```

for tow time to make space but I'm sure there is more effective way too.

Comment: I guess `\vspace{3cm}` (try any length you like) instead of the two empty sections does the job. Or am I not understanding correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As vaettchen already said in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124896/how-it-is-possible-to-make-a-vertical-space-between-first-paragraph-with-top-of#comment280117_124896), `\vspace` can be used. The original `\@maketitle` of class `article` uses internally `\vskip1.5em`. `\vspace` is the user-interface of LaTeX for `\vskip`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\newcommand{\Hrule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.3mm}}

\makeatletter% since there's an at-sign (@) in the command name
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
  \newpage
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% don't indent paragraphs in the title block
  \centering
  {\Large \bfseries\textsc{\@title}}
  \HRule\par%
  \textit{\@author \hfill \@date}
  \par
  \vspace{4\baselineskip}%
}
\makeatother% resets the meaning of the at-sign (@)

\title{Statement of Purpose}
\author{Sina Gholizadeh}
\date{Ph.D. Applicant}

\begin{document}
  \maketitle% prints the title block

\noindent
This is an example.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

**Remarks:**

- I have added `\newpage` at the beginning of the title as in `article.cls`.